# JMX file with Multiple Thread Groups executing on 3 remote machines, how to control the traffic for 2nd thread group only using one LG out of 3

Tags: java, jmeter

I have two thread group in JMX and trying to run using Gitlab pipeline,On one thread group all the 3 Windows Load generators are used, but in second thread group I only want to use 1 LG out of 3 LGs.
On Second thread group we have put a if controller and passing condition as "{__machineIP())"=="10.0.0.3", in this expression I am hard coding the IP, and this is **perfectly working fine** when I am passing command like:
**jmeter.bat -n -t C:\GitLab-Runner\Builds\<Location or path of JMX script>.jmx -R 10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.3 -l <Path and name of jtl file>.jtl -GNoOfThreads_TG1=1,-GRampUpPeriod_TG1=3 -GNoOfLoops_TG1=2 -GNoOfThreads_TG2=1,-GRampUpPeriod_TG2=1 -GNoOfLoops_TG2=2**

TG1: Thread Group 1 where 1 threads are distributed across 3 LGs so total load is 3 on Application

TG2: Thread Group 2

But now I want to pass as variable in gitlab so instead on hardcoding the IP , on if controller  I am changing expression like **"{__machineIP())"=="${__P(LG_TG2)"}** and passing the command like:
**jmeter.bat -n -t C:\GitLab-Runner\Builds\<Location or path of JMX script>.jmx -R 10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.3 -l <Path and name of jtl file>.jtl -GNoOfThreads_TG1=1,-GRampUpPeriod_TG1=3 -GNoOfLoops_TG1=2 -JNoOfThreads_TG2=1,-JRampUpPeriod_TG2=1 -JNoOfLoops_TG2=2 -JLG_TG2=10.0.0.3**

After executing the command using pipeline **Thread Group1(TG1) is executed successfully** but **it doesn't execute Thread Group2(TG2)**.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the property via `-G` command-line argument.

To wit change `-JLG_TG2=10.0.0.3` to `-GLG_TG2=10.0.0.3`

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)